# Facebook app - Do i need those permissions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-social-plugins

I created an app for my clients. They uses this app from their website to post on their Facebook Page (and as the Facebook Page).

1. they use a Facebook Login button to connect to Facebook (with an account that can publish post on the page) from their website,
2. they complete a form
3. when the form is submitted, an article is created on the website AND a post is created on the FaceBook Page.

I ask for **publish_action** permission and **manage_page** permission when the user connects.

Those permissions need a review from Facebook, so I ask for it but the FB team says that I "*only need those permissions when I use a public-facing Login*". Is that not the case?

Currently, my app only work when I connect with the account that created the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need those permissions, but if the App is for your client only you don´t need to get them reviewed. Just add your client as Admin, Developer or Tester of your App and the permissions will work for him without review.

Comment: That's what I thought... I wanted to avoid this solution. If I'm not mistaken, the accounts need to be "developers accounts" to be Admin, Developer or Tester of the App. Well, if there is no other solution i'll do like that. Thank you for your answer !